# Tautology combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have:

> ($p_1 \land p_2 \land \lnot p_3 \land p_4 \land p_5) \to \lnot (p_1 \lor p_2 \lor p_3 \lor p_4 \lor p_5)$.

I want to prove if is tautology or not and explain why.

I did an array true or false with this 5.

I dont know after what to do. Is a better way to avoid the array? Please help

Comment: Are you trying to express $\lnot\;$?  I ask because you mention -] being "not".

Comment: For $\land$ (and) you can use \land as well as \lor for $\lor$ (or). You can use \lnot for $\lnot$.

Comment: In order to show that it is **not** a *tautology*, you have to find a suitable assignment that satisfy the antecedent (the LHS) and falsify the consequent (the RHS).

Comment: In order to falsify the RHS it is enough that one of the $p_i$ is assigned the value TRUE.

Comment: But in order to satisfy the LHS we must have $p_1,p_2,p_4, p_5$ TRUE and $p_3$ FALSE. Thus, this assignment (corresponding to a line in the truth table) will produce TRUE $\to$ FALSE, i.e. it shows that the formula is not a *tautology*.

Comment: Sorry, I did wrong.The exercise was telling to prove that this should be false.So what I did is TRUE -> ¬ (False) that makes True -> true so False.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\big(p_1 \land p_2\land \lnot p_3 \land p_4 \land p_5\big)\rightarrow \lnot \big(p_1\lor p_2 \lor p_3 \lor p_4 \lor p_5\big)$$

Let $a$ represent the left hand side of the implication.  Let $b$ represent the right hand side of the implication.

To show (prove) this can be false (i.e. not a tautology), we need to find truth-value assignments such that $a$ is true and $b$ is false, since $a\to b$  is false if and only if $a$ is true, and $b$ is false.

Hint: What happens when we assign $p_1, p_2, p_4, p_5$ as true, and $p_3$ as false?

Then the left hand side is true, but the right hand side is false under that truth-value assignment.  Hence the implication is false under the given truth value assignment.

A tautology requires that the statement (here, an implication) be true for *every* truth-value assignment of variables.

Hence the implication cannot be a tautology.

Comment: I confused with your answer I would like to write again the comment I had wrote up  and answer me to this I post again the comment.-->Sorry, I did wrong.The exercise was telling to prove that this should be false.So what I did is TRUE -> ¬ (False) that makes True -> true so False.Am I right?As a result it isn't tatology

Comment: No, true -> true is **always true**.  You need to find an assignment of truth values to the variables $p_1... p_5$, such that we end with true -> false, which by definition of implication, is FALSE

Comment: The exercise asking to prove that all this is false.If it is tautology true->false . Right?

Comment: If i don't want to be tautology I should prove true->true but as you wrote true ->true is always true

Comment: As I explain in my answer, it is false that the given expression (an implication), is a tautology.  i.e. it is not a tautology.  Tautologies are true no matter whether the variables are true or false.  So this is not a tautology, because it is not true that it is true no matter what.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I hope I've helped!